# BeautifulSoup does not read all elements within tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having a problem with beautifulSoup that does not find all content in each tag . I.e. for page 3549 it omits everything that is highlighted in blue in the following image:

[image]

Interesting is, that i.e. for page 30 I don't have that problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd

n_pages = 1
for page in range(3549, 3550):
    n_pages += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    outer_link = 'https://www.info-net.com.pl/firmy/pokaz/polska/page:' + str(page)

    response = requests.get(outer_link)

    outer_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
    firmyContainer = outer_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'firmy'})

    for firms in firmyContainer:
       print(firms)
```

I would appreciate any helpful hints on what causes the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: It's hard to tell the nesting from a source image like that. Can you check from the Elements tab to be sure that the DIV you want is inside the container?

Comment: For the prettified code please find a following image: https://imgur.com/a/lcxM07Q  The strange thing is, that variable outer_soup takes the whole proper HTML, however variable firmyContainer does not take all of the content from ('div', attrs={'id':'firmy'})

Answer (score 0):

It works very well you should take time to inspect the sites and see the differences

**Example #1**
Open website: https://www.info-net.com.pl/firmy/pokaz/polska/page:30

[image: Image of firmy]

Output of `outer_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'firmy'})[0]`

```
<div id="firmy">
    <div id="firmy_g"></div>
    <div id="firmy_m">
        <ol>
            <li id="fir0">
                <h3><a href="/wizytowka/urzad-miasta-w-krosnie-odrzanskim,174430.html" target="_new">URZĄD MIASTA w
                        Krośnie Odrzańskim </a></h3>
                <div class="adres">
                    <p>ul. Parkowa 1</p>
                    <p>66-600 Krosno Odrzańskie</p>
                    <p>lubuskie</p>
                    <p><img src="/images/layout/koperta.png" alt="Adres emailowy"> <a
                            href="mailto:sekretariat@krosnoodrzanskie.pl"
                            title="Napisz emaila do: sekretariat@krosnoodrzanskie.pl">sekretariat@krosnoodrzanskie.pl</a>
                    </p>
                    <p><img src="/images/layout/www.png" alt="Adres www"> <a target="_new"
                            href="http://www.krosnoodrzanskie.pl" title="Przejdź do strony">www.krosnoodrzanskie.pl</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 15px;" class="img-shadow"><a
                        href="/wizytowka/urzad-miasta-w-krosnie-odrzanskim,174430.html" target="_new"><img
                            title="URZĄD MIASTA w Krośnie Odrzańskim" class="logo"
                            src="/upload/logo/logo_174430.jpg"></a></div>
                <p><img src="/images/layout/telefon.png" alt="telefon"> 68 383 50 17 centrala</p>
                <p><img src="/images/layout/telefon.png" alt="telefon"> 68 383 51 10</p>
                <p><img src="/images/layout/telefon.png" alt="telefon"> 68 383 52 26</p>
                <p><img src="/images/layout/telefon.png" alt="telefon"> fax 68 383 51 22</p>
                <div style="float:left;clear:both;"></div><span class="opis">
                    <p>Godziny otwarcia Urzędu:<br>poniedziałek: 8:00-16:00, wtorek-piątek: 7:30-15:30</p>
                </span>
                <p class="cardList-company-desc-more">

                    <a target="_new" href="/wizytowka/urzad-miasta-w-krosnie-odrzanskim,174430.html">więcej »</a>

                </p>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="slowa_k">Słowa kluczowe: <h4><a class="slowa" title="urząd miejski"
                    href="/portal/szukaj/urząd miejski">urząd miejski</a></h4>, </div>
        <div class="slowa_k">Branże: <h4><a class="slowa" title="Instytucje, Urzędy, Organizacje"
                    href="/firmy/polska/instytucje-urzedy/administracja-organizacje-urzedy">Instytucje, Urzędy,
                    Organizacje</a></h4>, </div>
    </div>
    <div id="firmy_d"></div>
</div>
```

**Example #2**
Open website: https://www.info-net.com.pl/firmy/pokaz/polska/page:3549

[image: Image of firmy]

Output of `outer_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'firmy'})[0]`

```
<div id="firmy">
    <div id="firmy_g"></div>
    <div id="firmy_m">
        <ol>
            <li id="fir0">
                <h3><a href="/b/274534">DR-TRUCK </a></h3>
                <div class="adres">
                    <p>al. Żwirki i Wigury 6</p>
                    <p>08-400 Garwolin</p>
                    <p>mazowieckie</p>

                </div>
                <p><img src="/images/layout/telefon.png" alt="telefon"> 508 845 244</p>
                <div style="float:left;clear:both;"></div>
                <p class="cardList-company-desc-more">
                    <a target="_new" href="/b/274534">więcej »</a>
                </p>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="slowa_k">Branże: <h4><a class="slowa" title="Handel samochodami/ Motocyklami, Wypożyczalnie"
                    href="/firmy/polska/motoryzacja-transport-spedycja/motoryzacja-handel-samochodami--motocyklami-wypozyczalnie">Handel
                    samochodami/ Motocyklami, Wypożyczalnie</a></h4>, </div>
    </div>
    <div id="firmy_d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @HedgeHog, but here is a problem. Python, omits the second part, not including <div class="slowa_k"> at all, when parsing page 3549. Please take a look at the below screenshot and my output of the same print that you have done.<img src="https://imgur.com/a/uzvd7hj"> <br/> Perhaps could we reach out via any tool, so that I can show you running my script ?

Answer (score 0):

@MaciekDubaj: Could reproduce the behavior - Tried to fetch data from a different location. Page loaded very slowly, it took several seconds and the result was without `slowa_k` as you described. Switched to [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) this behavior was fixed.

**Solution with Selenium**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
URL = 'https://www.info-net.com.pl/firmy/pokaz/polska/page:' + str(3549)

driver.get(URL)
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait for seconds

outer_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
firmyContainer = outer_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'firmy'})
        
outer_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'firmy'})[0]

driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
<div id="firmy"><div id="firmy_g"></div><div id="firmy_m"><ol><li id="fir0"><h3><a href="/b/60852">Dr Nauk Med. Spec. Dermatolog Wenerolog </a></h3><div class="adres"><p>ul. Farna 2</p><p>85-101 Bydgoszcz</p><p>kujawsko - pomorskie</p>
</div><p><img alt="telefon" src="/images/layout/telefon.png"/>  52 349 33 19</p><div style="float:left;clear:both;"></div><p class="cardList-company-desc-more">
<a href="/b/60852" target="_new">więcej »</a>
</p><div style="clear:both;"></div></li></ol><div class="slowa_k">Branże: <h4><a class="slowa" href="/firmy/polska/uslugi/medycyna-dermatologia-alergologia" title="Dermatologia, Alergologia">Dermatologia, Alergologia</a></h4>, </div></div><div id="firmy_d"></div></div>
```